# SpringBoot @interface to summarize different annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have an own annotations for Unit testing which looks like

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Transactional(rollbackFor = MyException.class)
public @interface DefaultTestAnnotations {
}
```

My different test classes are annotated like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
// @SpringBootTest() <--------------(1)
@DefaultTestAnnotations
public class MyTest1 extends Basic4Tests {
```

When I run `MyTest1` individually than it succeed. If I run it within an larger compound it fails due to some strange DB entities failures. I skip the details for the sake of brevity.

When I uncomment (1) than the tests - either individually or in a compound - succeeds. Now I thought that the anntoation 
`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` 
is already enough. But obviously not.

Has anybody an idea

- What can be summarized in the `@interface` declaration? In sense of that these are used and are 'meaningful'
- Why do I need to specify the `@SpringBootTest()` again? I thought declaring in the `interface` is sufficient.

**UPDATE**:

'to some strange DB entities failures' - means that the test saves data into the DB and when retrieving it fails to restore enums properly. The raised exceptions indicate that some spurious data is retrieved which seems to be never stored. Tracking the specific issue is out of scope for this question since I found a solution - which I do **NOT** understand. To avoid running into similar issues I want more clarity how `@interface` could be used.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific than: "some strange DB entities failures"

Comment: "it fails to restore enums"? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry - I don't want to investigate the DB problem. I want to have a clue why I need `SpringBootTest` twice. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your manipulating your data in the database in one test and so the next test does not have the data you are assuming. Spring reuses the application context between tests for performance reasons and does not reset it.

There are two solutions:
- use @DirtiesContext annotation on your test
- clean and setup your db before each test

Comment: since you are only "guessing" to what the actual problem is, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: q is now updated; What do you mean with 2 solutions? I see only one suggestion. The annoation `@DirtiesContext` looks promising but doesn't help.

Comment: @LeO first solution he recommends: use DirtiesContext, second is: clean and setup your db before each test.